# Need Help for FoxPro Select WHERE works, but Replace ALL FOR Fails?

Tags: select, replace, command, foxpro

I have this select statement that works in a FoxPro command window to return the 7 records where the objname is documents-mltry and the word "roster" appears in the descrip memo field:

`SELECT objname, descrip FROM archives where UPPER(OBJNAME)==[DOCUMENTS-MLTRY] AND [ROSTER]$UPPER(DESCRIP)`

However, when i then try to do a replace all statement to change the objname to "Roster" it fails telling me the "variable roster is not found". Note: the LIKE command is not available in this version of FoxPro.

Can anybody see what i am doing wrong in the replace command below?

`REPLACE ALL objname WITH "Roster" FOR UPPER(OBJNAME)==[DOCUMENTS-MLTRY] AND [ROSTER]$UPPER(DESCRIP)`

I have tried using ATC command in the replace statement that results in the same variable not found error message:

`REPLACE ALL objname WITH "Roster" FOR UPPER(OBJNAME)==[DOCUMENTS-MLTRY] AND ATC("ROSTER", descrip)`

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: After creating a [minimal-reproducible-example][1] by adding a 1st `Create Cursor/Table` line, your proposed code lines all run w/o any Error here: What version of `foxpro` do you use?

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your Square Brackets usage is unusually extensive, they are the third quotation mark type in `foxpro`, and I'd suggest to use 'single' and "double" quotation marks preferably because square brackets can also be used to refer to #define'd [constant_names] in `foxpro`

Comment: FoxPro is wrapped inside an old piece of software and it reports it is VFP version 9.00.0000.5818 EXE Support Library for Windows. I only used the brackets because the software submits its queries to the FoxPro backend that way. I'll try your suggestion of quotes instead. We're trying to cleanup the data in the old app before migration to a new online version of the software that is no longer based on FoxPro.

Comment: That version number is quite up-to-date, most recent major version, just a few Service Packs missing. Your code works without any errors here in Version `Vfp9 SP2`, i.e. `Visual FoxPro 09.00.0000.7423 for Windows [Feb 23 2009 13:20:28]`. so that your question Tag could be `visual-foxpro` instead of just `foxpro`

Comment: The missing first minimal-repro line here was `CREATE CURSOR archives (objname C(20), descrip M)`, just in case you have an occasion to run that `mcve` on your side, and maybe find the error(s) just being caused by occasional typo(s)?

Comment: SOLVED: Turns out there was an extra space after DOCUMENTS-MLTRY and since i wanted exact match it would never match. Once i added the extra space then it matched and worked. It's always the little things that get you.... MANY THANKS FOR TRYING TO HELP.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a WAG but I noticed that you are not using the (optional) alias or workarea in your REPLACE command. If the table you are REPLACEing is not SELECTed and the work area that is selected is another table, then you will receive a variable not found error. To test out this theory, add an "IN archives" to your REPLACE command. That might fix it.

**REPLACE ALL objname WITH "Roster" FOR UPPER(OBJNAME)==[DOCUMENTS-MLTRY] AND ATC("ROSTER", descrip) in archives**